# no NVIDIA GPU detected

Tags: debian, nvidia

I'd like to [install NVIDIA driver](http://www.nvidia.fr/download/driverResults.aspx/101470/fr) on debian, but the installer tells me that I've no NVIDIA GPU on my machine.

```
$ lspci -nn | grep NVIDIA
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 740M] [10de:0fdf] (rev a1)

$ nvidia-detect
no NVIDIA GPU detected.
```

How can I install this driver ?

Comment: What provided the `nvidia-detect` tool? The binary NVIDIA package or in the repository?

Comment: I've installed it manually `sudo apt install nvidia-detect`

Comment: Right.  The `nvidia-detect` package is not part of that binary.  The binary is not part of the system's repos.  I don't know how nvidia-detect works, but I do know there's *always* incompatibilities with nvidia's binary and the system repos.  

Additionally, can you provide the exact command(s) and output/errors that you see?

Answer (score 3):

The latest version of the NVIDIA drivers doesn't support your graphics chipset.

You should install the appropriate version as provided via the `non-free` repositories hosted by Debian. The full instructions are on [the Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#Version_340.96), but basically for your 740M, you need version 340.96, available for Jessie (which I'm assuming is the version you're using, Debian 8) as follows:

- add `contrib` and `non-free` to the Jessie line in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, so it looks something like

  ```
  deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
  ```
- update the package caches and install the necessary packages:

  ```
  aptitude update
  aptitude -r install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') nvidia-legacy-304xx-kernel-dkms
  ```
- create the appropriate [configuration file](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#configure);
- reboot.

Comment: That's a mobile chipset and probably not connected to the display, you'll also need bumblebee to get it working.